# New vector based on comparing elements of two other vectors "lagged"?

Tags: r

I have two vectors, `subject` and `target`. I want to create a new vector based on comparisons between the two existing vectors, with elements being compared `lagged`. I've solved this okay using the loop below, but I'm essentially wondering whether there's a more elegant solution using `apply`?

```
subject <- c(200, 195, 190, 185, 185, 185, 188, 189, 195, 200, 210, 210)
target <- c(subject[1], subject[1]-cumsum(rep(perweek, length(subject)-1)))
adjtarget <- target                                               

for (i in 1:(length(subject)-1)) {
  if (subject[i] > adjtarget[i]) {                
    adjtarget[i+1] <- adjtarget[i]           
   } else {                                       
    adjtarget[i+1] <- adjtarget[i]-perweek  }
   }
 }
```

Comment: What's the value of the perweek variable?

Comment: Hi sorry forgot this:
perweek is just any integer.
In my case, it's 
perweek <- 2

Comment: The code is a bit tricky to understand. In the loop, the assignments change `adjtarget` at the place which you will compare to in the next iteration.

I'm afraid there's no elegant solution to express this in R, where you usually work on whole vectors in parallel.

The comparison is a moving target

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exactly solve your problem, but may point in a helpful direction. I'm disregarding the interplay between changing `adjtarget` and comparing to it, and show a similar problem, where we compare to the constant `target`.  Then it's possible to change the `if` in the loop to a vector comparison:

```
lv <- but.last(subject) > but.last(target)
ind <- which(lv)
```

Prepare the result vector (I'll call it `x`, as it won't be the same result as your `adjtarget`) as a shifted copy of `target` and assign the changes to it:

```
x <- c(target[1], but.last(target))  # corresponds to the true branch of the `if`
x[ind+1] <- target[ind] - perweek    # corresponds to the false branch
```

Alternatively,

```
x <- c(target[1], but.last(target) - (!lv)*perweek
```

As I said, this doesn't solve your problem, but perhaps we could start from here.

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarification, if I understand your code, this is the kind of result you're looking for...

```
> (goal <- cbind(subject,target,adjtarget))

      subject target adjtarget
 [1,]     200    200       200
 [2,]     195    198       198
 [3,]     190    196       196
 [4,]     185    194       194
 [5,]     185    192       192
 [6,]     185    190       190
 [7,]     188    188       188
 [8,]     189    186       186
 [9,]     195    184       186
[10,]     200    182       186
[11,]     210    180       186
[12,]     210    178       186
```

If I'm right, then the challenge to vectorizing this is the repeated assignment of 186 in adjtarget. Vectorized code will evaluate the right hand side (RHS) before assigning it to the left hand side (LHS). So, the vectorized code won't see the updated value in adjtarget at row 9 until after the assignment is finished.

```
> y <- ifelse(subject > target, 1, 0) # matches TRUE case
> x <- target
> x[ind+1] <- target[ind]
> cbind(goal, x, y)
      subject target adjtarget   x y
 [1,]     200    200       200 200 0
 [2,]     195    198       198 198 0
 [3,]     190    196       196 196 0
 [4,]     185    194       194 194 0
 [5,]     185    192       192 192 0
 [6,]     185    190       190 190 0
 [7,]     188    188       188 188 0
 [8,]     189    186       186 186 1
 [9,]     195    184       186 186 1 # assigned correctly (?)
[10,]     200    182       186 184 1 # incorrect x; should be 186
[11,]     210    180       186 182 1 # incorrect x; should be 186
[12,]     210    178       186 180 1 # incorrect x; should be 186
```